# Deciding whether or not a class of modules is "big enough"

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules

For the last few days I'm pondering the following question. The situation is this: $R$ is a commutative ring and $A$ a (noncommutative) $R$-algebra. I have a class $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\coprod_{S} SA-\textbf{Mod}$ of $A$-modules where $S$ runs over all commutative $R$-algebras. I want to know if $\mathcal{C}$ is "big enough". More precisely: I want to know if $I:=\bigcap_{V\in\mathcal{C}} \ker(A\to \mathrm{End}_{S-\textbf{Mod}}(V))$ is the zero ideal.

I already know the following facts from the construction of $\mathcal{C}$ and $A$:

- $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under extension of scalars: If $V\in SA-\textbf{Mod}$ is in $\mathcal{C}$, then $TV$ is in $\mathcal{C}$ for any $S\to T$.
- $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under direct sums: If $V_i\in SA-\textbf{Mod}$ are in $\mathcal{C}$, then so is $\bigoplus_i V_i$.
- If $S$ is a field, then $SA-\textbf{Mod}\subseteq\mathcal{C}$.
- More generally: If $V\in SA-\textbf{Mod}$ is free as an $S$-module and $S$ has the property that projective $S$-modules are always free (like principal ideal domains or local rings) then $V\in\mathcal{C}$.
- All $V\in\mathcal{C}\cap SA-\textbf{Mod}$ are free as $S$-modules.

This suggests to me that $I$ might be contained in $nil(R)A$. Is this true?

If it helps, $R$ is an integral domain. More specifically $R=k[v^{\pm 1}]$ oder $R=k[v^{\pm 1}, u^{\pm 1}]$ with $k$ either $\mathbb{Z}[2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{m})]$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ or some localization of these rings at a small set of prime numbers.

$A$ is given by generators and relations (specifically it is a quotient of a path algebra) but I do not know much more about $A$ itself. In particular, I do not know, if $A$ is free as an $R$-module (in which case the answer to my question would be "yes").

EDIT:
Since I was asked: $SA$ denotes the scalar extension $S \otimes_R A$, $TV$ analogously means $T \otimes_S V$.

Johannes Hahn.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding something, so I will leave this as a comment.  The "regular representation" ($A$ acting on $A$ via, say, right multiplication) gives a homomorphism $A\to \mathrm{End}_{R-\textbf{Mod}}(A)$.  Isn't this already injective, so that your ideal is $I = 0$?

Comment: Yes, this is injective, but since I do not know whether or not $A\in\mathcal{C}$ holds, I cannot immediately conclude $I=0$.